# Call startActivityForResult get image in gallery from customview of viewgroup kill my application

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I have two activity A and B. In activity A, I click a button to go activity B. In activity B, I have a custom view of viewgroup. In this customview, I want to get image in gallery of phone, so I used to `((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(i, 1);` to go my gallery. But after that, my application is killed (B acivity is killed).

Somebody said I should call startActivityForResult on main activity (B activity), so in customview, i send a broadcast to activity B. In activity B, I received action then I call startActivityForResult  to pick image in gallery, but it doesn't work.

Case 1: when pick image in gallery from customview

```
   public void draw_multi(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GET_SINGLE_FILE);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Case 2: send broadcast from customview and receiver in activity B

```
public void draw_multi(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX() / scale;
    float y = event.getY() / scale;

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(ACTION_FILTER);
    i.putExtra("action", ACTION_SHOW_NOTIFICATION_MUPDF);
    i.putExtra("xLoca", x);
    i.putExtra("yLocal", y);
    i.putExtra("pageNumber", this.getPageNumber());

    mContext.sendBroadcast(i);

}
```

Receiver in actyvity B

```
    private class PDFReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras().containsKey("action")) {

            String resultAction = intent.getExtras().getString("action");
            switch (resultAction) {
                case ACTION_SHOW_NOTIFICATION_MUPDF:
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is error log, i have not selected image from the list

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 3299828 bytes
    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:160)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:891)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7539)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
 Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 3299828 bytes
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1147)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:3981)
    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:891) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7539) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958) 2019-04-18 23:54:37.148 10237-10237/tve.tve.vnulic I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10237 SIG: 9
```

How can I fix this? Please help me, thank you!!!

Comment: share error logcat.

Comment: please share your code, its difficult to provide solution without knowing what you have actually done in your code.

Comment: Show logcat that indicates why your Activity is killed (or crashes).

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for reply, I have edited my question, thank you